# Devise: change password reset_password_token is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using Devise & I am trying to create a new form where user's can reset their passwords, but I am getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_reset_password_token"
```

The reason this is happening is because the reset_password_token generated from

```
<%= f.hidden_field :reset_password_token %>
```

is empty. Ex:

```
<input id="user_reset_password_token" name="user[reset_password_token]" type="hidden">
```

Here is the controller action

```
  def update_password
    @user = current_user
    # raise params.inspect
    if @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
      sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
      redirect_to '/account_settings', :notice => "Your Password has been updated!"
    else
      redirect_to '/account_settings', :notice => "Your Password was not changed. Try again"
    end
  end
```

Here is my form
**edit_password.html.erb**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>

<hr/>
<%= render :template => 'users/edit_password_form', 
                    :locals => { :resource => current_user, :resource_name => "user" } %>
```

**edit_password_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => "password/users/update_password", :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
<%# devise_error_messages! %>
<%= f.hidden_field :reset_password_token %>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 "> 
        <%= f.label :current_password, "Current Password:" %>   
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 ">
        <%= f.password_field :current_password, :placeholder =>"Current Password" %>
    </div>  
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 ">
        <%= f.label :password, "New Password:" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 "><%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder=>"New Password" %>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 ">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm New Password:" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 ">
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder=>"Confirm New Password" %>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<%= f.submit "Change my password", :class => "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this has nothing to do with the built-in devise functionality where they can be sent an email to reset their password when they've forgotten it.  Instead, it looks like you are allowing them to enter their current password and then choose a new one.  In that case, I don't think you want the `reset_password_token` in the form at all, as it's irrelevant, i.e. you can just remove the line:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :reset_password_token %>
```